# ConfigurationBuilder for Core Api from legacy dotnet framework 4.7.1 app

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core, .net-core-configuration

Trying to create a `IConfigurationRoot` type object to consume Core 2.2 Api from legacy dotnet framework 4.7.1 WPF app config file.

```
myCoreApiController.CoreApiMethod( confirutation); // (IConfigurationRoot configuration)
```

First defined a Dictionary and load it with keys that identify your configuration settings and values (the actual settings). That code looks like this:

```
var settings = new Dictionary<string, string> 
{  
    {"toDoService:url", "http://..."},  
    {"toDoService:contractid", "???"}   
};
```

Then created a `ConfigurationBuilder`, add my Dictionary of configuration settings to it and use that `ConfigurationBuilder` to build an `IConfiguration` object.

Here's that code:

```
var cfgBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
cfgBuilder.AddInMemoryCollection(settings);
IConfiguration cfg = cfgBuilder.Build();
```

But the `ConfigurationBuilder` is also an Interface. So I can't create instance of that.
  Then I tried to implement that and create my own but could not over override `AddInMemoryCollection` static method.
So the upper solution is not working.

Please note that the project has the NuGet Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration, Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions are installed.

Hope, some one will share their way to achieve that.

Comment: `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilder` is not an interface. It's a class with a public constructor. What's your issue?

Answer (score 2):

I just encountered this 'issue'. My problem was that I had:

```
using System.Configuration;
```

but what I need is:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
```

Answer (score 0):

[**`ConfigurationBuilder.Build`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.configurationbuilder.build/?#Microsoft_Extensions_Configuration_ConfigurationBuilder_Build) method returns [**`IConfigurationRoot`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.iconfigurationroot), which is derived from [**`IConfiguration`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.iconfiguration)

but in your code, you assign the built configuration to `IConfiguration`

```
IConfiguration cfg = cfgBuilder.Build();
```

it was indicated that the target method is defined as

```
CoreApiMethod(IConfigurationRoot configuration);
```

The issue is trying to pass the assigned `IConfiguration` variable to the target function as `IConfigurationRoot`.

Use the appropriate type when assigning the variable.

```
var settings = new Dictionary<string, string> { 
    {"toDoService:url", "http://..."},  
    {"toDoService:contractid", "???"}   
}; 

IConfigurationRoot configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddInMemoryCollection(settings)
    .Build();

myCoreApiController.CoreApiMethod(confirutation);
```

Comment: As I mentioned, we can't create instance of ConfigurationBuilder. For that reason I wanted custom implementation of that.
Error is
"can not create an instance of the abstract class or interface ConfigurationBuilder"

Comment: @MetallicSkeleton [ConfigurationBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.configurationbuilder?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.0) is not abstract. You need to edit the post and clarify the **actual** problem.